# Creating a Kinesis Stream on existing DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis

I already have an existing DynamoDB table when regularly gets updated with data from an upstream source. How can I create a new Kinesis stream to consume updates from the table in AWS CDK?

From other posts, I see that the ddb table must be enabled with streaming at the time of creation. Is there a workaround for this in CDK?

Comment: It doesn't have to be enabled at the time of creation. Is your table being created by CDK?

Comment: yes it is created in CDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply enable KDS on DynamoDB by passing the newly created stream as `IStream` into the `kinesisStream` parameter of your tables construct.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.Table.html#kinesisstream

Comment: The table is already created in CDK and is being used by other workflows, will this be a problem if I change the table construct? (I apologize if this is a silly question, I'm new to using AWS services and still learning on the go)

Comment: No such thing as a silly question. No, updating the kinesis stream in the construct will have no downtime on your table. It could be beneficial to set the retention policy to retain before making changes, and perhaps take a back-up just to be safe. But if things are done correctly there would be no issue.